# Accessing Seismic attributes in petrel from ocean

Tags: ocean, petrel

How can I access Seismic attriubte estimated by volume attributes generator virtually i.e without publishing them in seismic collections tree??

Comment: I want to access them via ocean as i want to use these attributes in my background calculation

Answer (score 0):

Virtual seismic attributes always show up in the tree under a SeismicCube (source geometry). Is there any reason to hide the virtual attribute cube?

Comment: As I am using these attributes in background calculations i dont want to show them in tree as i am using many of them.

Comment: There is no way to hide an attribute, but you can remove it in the same module when you finish.